# Imprimir campo al azar de una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo un pequeño problema tengo un codigo funcional el cual me genera una palabra al azar

```
$codigo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM palabras WHERE categoria='b'");
mt_srand(time()); 
$max = mysql_num_rows($codigo);
$rand = mt_rand(1,$max); 
$obtener = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM palabras WHERE sub_categoria='$rand' AND categoria='b'");
while($ban = mysql_fetch_array($obtener)) { echo $ban['palabra']; }
```

pero ahora necesito eliminar el campo sub_categoria por otras necesidades e intente el siguiente codigo

```
$codigo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM palabras WHERE categoria='b'");
mt_srand(time()); 
$max = mysql_num_rows($codigo);
$rand = mt_rand(1, $max); 
$ban = mysql_fetch_array($codigo)
echo $ban['palabra'][$rand];
```

pero resulta que no me funciona, me bota unas letras que no estan en la base de datos, si me ayudaran seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: ¿Qué esperas obtener cuando haces `echo $ban['palabra'][$rand];`? Con $ban['palabra'] obtienes la palabra del primer registro pero ¿para qué le aplicas otro índice?

Answer (score 0):

La posible solución que encontrado estaria en la siguiente pagina:
[Metodo ROW_NUMBER()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)

La pagina hace mencion del metodo  ROW_NUMBER(), este metodo sirve para extraer el o los campos de una tabla deacuerdo a su posicion, se aplicaria en reemplazo del siguiente codigo (el primer codigo de la pregunta que tiene el sub_categoria).

```
$obtener = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM palabras WHERE sub_categoria='$rand' AND categoria='b'");
```

Considerando que sub_categoria es un campo numerico que deseas eliminar, para obtener la consulta debes ordenar la tabla palabras y extraer en campo con $rand como posicion.

//Azar = valor del campo de la tabla palabras

```
    SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
 ORDER BY Azar
 ) row_num,
Azar
FROM 
 palabras
ORDER BY 
Azar
where row_num=$rand
 ;
```

Comment: Me olvidaba la ultima consulta lo debes igualar a $obtener = mysql_query(**consulta**);